# why is Issues tab not present in my repo's github page?

Tags: git, github

I want to create issues in a github repo to correct technical debt in the repo. I am not able to see the issues tab. For other repos the issues tab present below the pull request tab. How can I enable the issues tab for my repo?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to enable the Issues first. You can do that by clicking to **Settings** and enable the Issues section. Then you can use it.

[image]

Comment: I cannot find Options in Settings, nor can I find Issues anywhere in the huge list of Settings pages.  I can only guess that this has been completely revamped since this was posted in 2017.  Does anyone have up-to-date info on how to do this?

Comment: @Jay Imerman, I've added a POST with the steps for Year 2022. Quick Answer: Click Settings -> General -> Features; Click the checkbox to enable Issues; Health!

Answer (score 7):

In the Year 2022, here are the steps to enable the ISSUES setting:

1. Click Settings -> General -> Features
2. Click the checkbox to enable Issues

[image]

Done! Health!