# Github: How to write an Issue on someone else's fork when there's no 'Issues' tab?

Tags: github

I want to write an issue on someone else's fork, but there's no tab for it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just a thought: Fork the fork, create an issue and mention the forker. But this might have a slight overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the fork owner to enable issues first. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29692689/2404492).
As for how to contact the Github user, it can be tricky because there's no private messages in Github since 2012.